# Broken css/image links after moving

Tags: deployment

I've been trying to fix an issue with moving my drupal installation.

Some first information:

- I am using the Open Social module;
- I used a localhost a DNS to connect my Xampp to the same subdomain as I now on my FTP, so the links are identical.
- I currently have turned off CSS aggregation to be able to see anything, otherwise the CSS is completely broken;

It seems like my theme css and image links have been broken due to moving my Drupal installation.

The only error I seem to get is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" into the console.

How I moved my Drupal installation:

1. back-upped the database through phpmyadmin
2. copied the insides of my xampp's  "htdocs" folder into a back-up folder
3. imported my database sql dump into the new database
4. uploaded the files from the back-up folder into my FTP
5. adjusted the settings.php file to communicate with the database.

I'm getting stuck in options as i don't know what is causing this.

Comment: Did you flush the sites caches after moving?

Comment: There's so many possible errors you could have made it's hard to make a guess but I would start by opening an image url in its own window to see what's shown. If it's just a 404, then I would double check that the file was actually copied to the right folder.

Comment: Yes i flushed the cache, many times. And when i open an image in its own page it gives me: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: You'll need to check your server logs to find out what it doesn't like. As mentioned there's lots of reasons so you'll need to find the error

Comment: can you share the url of referring to the broken images and  share the url of the new  location ( host, a url you access to the druapal instanse)

Comment: 99% of these cases are due to misconfigured `.htaccess` and/or Apache config.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by turning off the "Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews" option.